# 4 weeks or accounting month grouping in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a requirement to group data in transaction table into 4 week groups, or accounting month grouping, any suggestions on how to approach it on postgresql

Regards

Comment: That's nice, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Phill Have a look at this answer 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44415708/4193310

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(ITEM_C._demand) AS aggre_demand,ITEM_C._week as account_month  FROM (SELECT  sum(quantity) AS _demand,( CASE WHEN floor((extract(doy from shipment_date)-1)/7)+1 > 0 AND floor((extract(doy from shipment_date)-1)/7)+1 <=4 THEN 1 
ELSE (CASE WHEN floor((extract(doy from shipment_date)-1)/7)+1 >4 AND floor((extract(doy from shipment_date)-1)/7)+1 <=8 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END ) END)AS _week, date_trunc('year',shipment_date) AS _Year
FROM smp.shipment
GROUP BY floor((extract(doy from shipment_date)-1)/7)+1,date_trunc('year',shipment_date)) AS ITEM_C
GROUP BY ITEM_C._week, ITEM_C._Year
```

I think this is not the idle way to do this, as i need to repeat this 1..52 weeks total 13 times

Answer (score -1):

use date_trunc
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Anything more than this will need some more information. copy some examples and anything you have tried already.

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', your_date_field)
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY 1
```